# PHP Admin Panel opensource script

Tags: php

I am working on rapidly development of php websites, Is there any admin panel opensource script that can I customize ?

I don't mean full CMS for both admin and client pages only for Admin

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Comment: if you are looking for a core php one https://github.com/ajithjojo/zadmin-php-adminpanel use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of many more but personally i like yii framework. YII provides gii toll, which auto generate CRUD pages based on database table.

Comment: That's a full framework, though

Answer (score 2):

I know there's [Backendpro](http://www.kaydoo.co.uk/projects/backendpro), which claims to `"provide(s) you with functionality to do all the simple repetitive tasks like authentication, permissions and a basic look and feel for your websites control panel"` according to its website.

I never used it, though (and it looks like the development has halted more than a year ago) as usually trying to customize pre-made things can become harder that build them on your own from scratch. If you have done something similar in previous projects you can always re-use some of your code, otherwise I strongly doubt you can find anything like a pre-made admin panel, as it's very dependent on how you structure the whole site.

A rapid googling got me to this too:

http://www.apphp.com/php-adminpanel/index.php?page=examples

but by a skim of the website the Free version seems pretty lacking, and I don't know how it could work :)

**Edit**: as Sammaye noted, Backend Pro is built for the CI framework, just keep that in mind; you can use CI to develop your own panel now that you're at it, although it lacks the automatic CRUD generation that YII (or CakePHP, IIRC) has

Comment: Note backendpro is for CodeIgniter projects

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.

There are many themes for admin pages out there however there is not pre-built admin sections. It is kinda hard to make a pre-built admin script for a schema you don't know and for a envo you don't know and for a bunch of business rules you don't know as such there isn't really any.

As @VibhaJ made the suggestion, you would normally make the admin pages as part of the site itself using frameworks like Yii or your own.